# CompletionProvider for a specific Monaco editor instance

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Monaco Editor allows registering a custom completion provider via `monaco.languages.registerCompletionProvider`. However, this registers the provider globally across all instances for the given language.

In my specific case I want to provide auto completion of tables and columns in an SQL editor. But I have many instances and they need to use different sets of tables / columns.

Is there a way to register auto completion for only a specific editor instance?

Comment: I just asked this similar question (before finding this one)...did you ever solve this issue? I'm in the same boat as you and could use a hint.

Comment: I've opened this as an issue on GH, if you search for that you'll find the answer by the maintainers. It's possible, but sort of cumbersome to do. I ended up not actually needing it.

Answer (score 3):

No you can’t, they go into a global registry.
But the provider is passed the editor model as a parameter, so you can just only provide completion items for the model/editor you are interested in, and return empty for the others.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can, but it is a bit cumbersome.

The premise is that the registration returns a disposable, which enables disposing (i.e. remove/unregister), and that the providers are additive (not exclusive).

lets assume you have your own function: `registerMyCompletion`:

```
fuction registerMyCompletion(monaco, provider) {
  return monaco.languages.registerCompletionProvider(provider).dispose; 
}
```

Now in your component:

```
const [dispose, setDispose] = useState();

  <div
    onFocus={() => setDispose(registerCompleteion(...)}
    onBlur={() => setDispose(prevDispose => {
     if(prevDispose) {
      prevDispose();
     }
     return null;
    })}
  >
    <Editor .... />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: This still registers it globally, though, so if you have multiple editor instances at the same time it'd be a problem. However, it can be solved using the other answer.